# JavaFX ComboBox items are getting cleared on selection

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I have a strange issue. I'm using a ComboBox in JavaFX where each item is an HBox and is a combination of an image and a label.

```
list.forEach(continent -> {
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(continent + ".png"));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setFitHeight(25);
    imageView.setFitWidth(25);
    imageCombo.getItems().add(new HBox(imageView, new Label(continent)));
 });
```

`list` is an array list of strings. `imageCombo` is just a `ComboBox<HBox>` Following is the result when I start my application.

[image: ComboBox displaying an image infront of every item]

No Issues till here. However, the issue comes when I choose one of the items. When I do, it gets selected but when I expand the combo box list again, the item which was previously selected becomes blank and if I select that Item, that will also be not visible. I tried to use Cell Factory, doesn't seem to help me much. Here is how the issue looks after selecting Europe and Africa for example. Observe that Africa is being shown as the currently selected item as that is the last chosen value.

[image: Europe and Africa are gone after choosing]

Comment: Inserting `Node` to `Combobox`'s items is not recommended by API Document.  [A warning about inserting Nodes into the ComboBox items list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html). So it might be solved by making data model for `ComboBox`'s items which has the image and the label string, with a cellfactory.

Comment: @monolith52 If you can show me how I can use cell factory to have an image and a string, it would be great. I couldn't get that working so I tried to do like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is pointed out in the comments: inserting `Node` to `Combobox`'s items is not recommended by API Document.

Your `ComboBox` could only store the `String` values instead:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("asia", "europe", "america"));
```

Then you could write a `ListCell` implementation like:

```
class MyListCell extends ListCell<String> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty)
            setGraphic(null);
        else {
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(item + ".png"));
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setFitHeight(25);
            imageView.setFitWidth(25);
            setGraphic(new HBox(imageView, new Label(item)));
        }

        setText("");
    }

}
```

And then use this implementation to show the `HBox`es in the dropdown list:

```
comboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new MyListCell());
```

And to show on the `ComboBox` itself:

```
comboBox.setButtonCell(new MyListCell());
```

---

**Note:** Normally the `ComboBox` should not store the string values, but instances of a class that represents a continent, like `Continent` that encapsulates the continent name and the image path.

Comment: worked like a charm